# Why I don't have Build File in my Flutter Project

Tags: flutter

Whenever i create a new project in flutter, I don't get the Build File! Why?
[image]

Comment: build/run the project

Comment: Sounds like your tool is broken. Since Flutter is open source, you can just retrieve the sources and find out yourself.

Comment: But how can i??

Answer (score 0):

your build file available in folder name Android, see below capture

[image]

Comment: No there isn't anything under Android File as you can see in the picture!